# question about importing models

Tags: modeling

whenever I try to import a 3d model from the internet into blender the colors don't show up.  how do you import 3d models from the internet and have the colors show in blender?

thanks:D

Comment: If the object is an .STL, there is no color.

Comment: can you [edit] your question to add more details? what kind of file are you importing? check [ask] for more info on how the site works.

Answer (score 1):

there is a lack of information in your question. What is the file extention? The model comes from another .blend file?

If it comes from another blender files the process you're looking for is to append something in your project. When you import a file to your project only the 3D information will transfer (vertices, edges and meshes). If you want to insert another informations such as materials, textures, etc you need to append these informations into your own blend file.

[image]

It is a step by step process, so I advise you to  see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CSVLI_6zmRw).

I hope it helps and welcome to the comunity :)